# Bootstrap is not working in my mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have created a website with bootstrap css.

I made it responsive. When building the website and testing in my laptop browser its working fine after i reduce the size of the browser but when i host that and test in my iPhone its showing the default view not the mobile view.

But when i test in my laptop browser its working properly.

what should i add in the page for mobile view?

am i missing something?

Please help me

Thanks

Comment: _"what should i add in the page for mobile view?"_ Isn't that on bootstrap documentation? _"am i missing something?"_ I don't know, hardly we can guess if you don't show a minimal working example of your code (BTW it may even help you to isolate the problem). I'd suggest to take some time to read SO FAQ, it'll help you to post better questions.

Comment: @Adriano People come here to get their problems solved, not to learn how to ask a question.

Comment: @Anup no. People come here to solve their problems **respecting community rules and guidelines**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you add `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` Meta in your head section?

Answer (score 2):

Adding this will work for you :-

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```